# Accommodating variable filename for python script

Tags: python, pandas

I have to read multiple filenames which i will be treating as input for my python script. But the input files may have variable name depending upon the time it got generated.

```
File1: RM_Sales_Japan_2011201920191124194200.xlsx
File2: RM_Volume_Australia_201120192019154321194200.xlsx
```

How to accommodate these changes while reading a file instead of exactly specifying the filename every time we run the script?

Things i tried:
I have used below method in my previous scripts because it had only one file with known extension:

```
xlsxfile = "*.xlsx"
filelocation = "/user/script/" + xlsxfile
```

But with multiple files with similar extension i am not sure how to get the definition done.

**EDIT1:**

I was trying to get more clarity on using glob with read_excel. Please see my example code below:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
os.chdir ('D:\\Users\\RMoharir\\Downloads\\Smart Spend\\Input')

fls=glob.glob("Medical*.*")

df1 = pd.read_excel(fls, parse_cols = 'A:H', skiprows = 10, header = None)
```

But this gives me an error:

```
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'list'>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why doesn’t pass filename as parameter to your script?

Comment: filename will change depending upon the generation time of the input file. so i just want to use a partial filename

Answer (score 2):

If you simply need to find all the files that match a given pattern in a directory, `os` and `re` modules have you covered.

```
import os
import re

files = os.listdir()

for file in files:
    if re.match(r".*\.xlsx$", file):
        print(file)
```

This short program will print out every file in the current directory whose name ends with `.xslx`.  If you need to match a more complicated pattern, you may need to read up on [Regular Expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

Note that `os.listdir` takes an optional string argument of what path to look in, if not given it will look in the directory the program was ran from

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I modified your solution as per my need:____________
```Python
    for fl in os.listdir():  
        if re.match(r"RM_.*\.xlsx$", fl):  
            print(fl)  
            df = pd.read_excel (fl, parse_cols = 'A:E', skiprows = 13, header = None)  
      
    df.head()  
```
  .
____________However, i am doing this for every file which does make my code a bit bigger. I am sure there is another way where each filename can be assigned to a different variable and that variable can be used instead of using the loop again and again.

Comment: Formatting in comments is not working. If there is ay other link than : https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting It would be great

Comment: @RahulMoharir You can't format multi-line code in comments.  I'm not sure I understand your problem, do you want to first store a list of filtered filenames then re-use that list instead of re-iterating through the directory multiple times?  You can use a site like pastebin.com to link to your current code, or just add it to your question

Comment: yes that's what am trying to do. Use the loop once and get all the files saved in unique variable to use it later in my code.